# Improve nested foreach performance C#

Tags: c#, foreach, windows-runtime, nested-loops

i have this following classes, in a windows store app project.

```
    public class Meeting
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Organizer { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MeetingType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; } //X = LAT; Y=LNG
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<MeetingPoint> MeetingPoints { get; set; }
    public List<MeetingInvitee> Invitees { get; set; }
}
```

and this one

```
public class MeetingPoint
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public List<Attchments> Attachments { get; set; }
    public List<MeetingPoint> SubPoints { get; set; }
    public int AttachmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
    public string executiveSummary { get; set; }
    public string presenter { get; set; }
    public string coPresenter { get; set; }
    public Double duration { get; set; }
    public string purpose { get; set; }
    public string supportedBy { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }

}
```

In one of the pages, i do a search  that looks like this, where i try to get the `Attachments` in each `SubPoint` of each `MeetingPoint`

```
foreach (var item in meeting.MeetingPoints)
        {
            foreach (var sub in item.SubPoints)

            {

                foreach (var at in sub.Attachments)
                {

                    ...

                }
            }
```

My question is if there is a more effective way of doing this, since having 3 nested foreach takes about 4 or 5 seconds.

Comment: How many elements do you have? And what's the stuff you do inside the loops?

Comment: If you need to loop through all `Attachments` for all `Subpoints` of all `Meetings`, then you will most likely have to loop through all `Attachments` for all `Subpoints` of all `Meetings`. It could be made more efficient if you don't need to loop through everything...

Comment: the number of elements varies, the stuff i do inside the loops is read the attachment info to a new object and add that object to a list.

Comment: @dubstylee unfortunately i do. Wasn't sure if there was a better way to do this with Linq or something, and thats why i asked :)

Comment: If what you really want is to "search", then perhaps you would be better off with a search engine, such as [Lucene.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms).

Comment: @NightOwl888 i used the tearm "Search", because i dindt know how to call it when i go through all Items > SubItems > SubSubItems ( not that good at english )

Comment: Show us what you are doing inside the `...`, if you are doing any kind of filtering you may be able to be smarter about it and not loop through every member.

Comment: If you need to go through all items the code you have will have best performance of all other approaches (short of possibly speedup using Parallel.ForEach which only would help if you actually can parallelize work in thread safe  way). You need to profile your code and see where you spend time - SO will not really be able to help with what currently shown in the post.

Comment: What portion of time is taken up by the loops vs the time spent within the body of the innermost loop? I'm guessing that the code you left out is actually the code to focus on (not that there are three loops).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about performance increase, I think you may see some, but if you want to get away from nested loops consider using lambda/SelectMany to get to the lowest collection you need to iterate over to do work against.  In other words, if you're only going to be operating against attachments then consider something like this:

```
 var greatGandChildrenFlattened = parent.Children.SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren.SelectMany(gc => gc.GreatGrandChildren));
 foreach (var item in greatGandChildrenFlattened)
 {
     //do work on item
 }
```

Comment: well it did improve a bit , but it was something like 0.3 secs :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace some of the `foreach` blocks with `Parallel.ForEach`. Just look for this in the output window "EventSourceException: No Free Buffers available from the operating system (e.g. event rate too fast)" and if it happens, replace one of the `Parallel.ForEach` invocations with a normal `foreach` block. This happens if events are fired too quickly and it may have a negative impact on the performance instead of helping you.

Comment: i have a couple of awaits call inside the stuff i do in the 3rd foreach

Comment: You should probably mention this in the question. It might be the awaitable code that makes the whole process slow. Can you try just commenting out the awaits calls to see if there is a major difference in the performance?

Comment: Be careful with Parallel.ForEach. If you plan on storing some data in a common collection, make sure it is thread safe or you will end up with nondeterministic result.